# hyperlinks to PDF files

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet in which I need to make hundreds of links to PDF files that are in the same folder on my computer.
The file name for the link appears in the Excel table.
Today I create each link separately, but I'm sure there is a simpler way to tell Excel to copy the link in the top box but look for the file whose name appears in the Excel table.

I'm doing each hyperlink separably

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A1` has the name of the hyperlink and `A2` has the location, use this formula where you want the link to appear:

`=HYPERLINK(A1,A2)`

You can then copy this down to the other cells.